# How to deal with leading zeroes while deserialising a JSON request?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json-deserialization, leading-zero

I have this piece of source code, used for deserialising a JSON request:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(telegram.ReceiveTelegram);
```

When my JSON request looks as follows, there is no problem:

```
{"Task":{...,"PosX":2278,"PosY":6500,...}}
```

When it looks as follows, I have an `Exception`:

```
{"Task":{...,"PosX":02278,"PosY":06500,...}}
```

This is the mentioned `Exception`:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Input string '02278' is not a valid number. Path 'State.PosX', line 1, position 385. ---> System.FormatException: Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.
> at System.ParseNumbers.StringToLong(String s, Int32 radix, Int32 flags, Int32* currPos)
> at System.Convert.ToInt64(String value, Int32 fromBase)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseReadNumber(ReadType readType, Char firstChar, Int32 initialPosition)

Apparently the deserialiser can't handle leading zeroes.

The target framework of my C# application is .NET Framework 4.6.1.

What can I do in order to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that when the property is numeric type in JSON, it can have the leading zero, unless it is a string.

Comment: `dynamic` <-- Ew. If you need broader JSON types then you should use `JToken` or `JObject` instead of `dynamic`, e.g. `JToken json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>( telegram.ReceiveTelegram )` - use `JObject` if you _know_ `telegram.ReceiveTelegram` is always a JSON object literal and not a JSON Array or other type.

Comment: The second one is not a valid JSON according to several online JSON validation tools.

Comment: It's definitely not valid, see the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-6

Comment: ??? Are you saying that leading zeroes are not valid JSON?

Comment: Correct, you need to put in quotes as a string

Comment: @Charlieface: please add your RFC reference in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Better question is what were you using to generate invalid JSON? Never generate it yourself, always use a proper serializer and parser

Comment: @Charlieface: I needed to test a list of JSON queries, one based on `prop=1`, another one on `prop=10`, so I decided to replace `prop=1` by `prop=01` in order to easily align them in Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not valid JSON** to have leading zeroes in a number that is not enclosed in quotes.

See [the offical spec, RFC8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-6):

> 6. **Numbers**
>    The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most programming languages.  A number is represented in base 10 using decimal digits.  It contains an integer component that may be prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by a fraction part and/or an exponent part.  **Leading zeros are not allowed.**